# Redirect URL issue in Safari and Opera with jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect the page if my website opened in Iframe with the following javascript code. But it is not working in Safari and Opera browsers.

```
var siteurl = '<?php echo $base_url;?>'; // My website url
var currentUrl = document.referrer; // The url where my website was opened in iframe

// Check if current url is not equal the original site url
if(siteurl !== currentUrl){
   // Then Redirect browser to original(siteurl)
   window.top.location.href = '<?php echo $base_url;?>';   
}
```

From Safari:

[image]

From Opera:

[image]

How can I fix this redirect problem. If there is a way, can you answer me please.

How to break out the iframe with javascript.

Comment: `document.referrer` has nothing to do with iframes. It's the URL of the page you came from when following a link.

Comment: @Barmar `document.referrer` just giving browser url, Of course it has nothing to do with iframe. I need to check the browser url so that I can redirect the original url with javascript.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/

Comment: @Ouroborus I have already try that but it is not working in safari and opera like my code.

Comment: The error message already said _why_ it doesn’t want to allow what you are trying to do, in pretty plain English …

Comment: The sandbox flag `allow-top-navigation` could perhaps fix that problem - but it would have to be set by the site that is embedding yours via iframe, and I am guessing their cooperation is likely rather not a given here.

Comment: Is the IFrame src set to your domain name?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to detect referer with PHP.  This one-liner will detect if the site is opened in an iframe and redirect the top location to same page.

```
this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);
```

However, modern browsers can prevent access to the parent for the security reasons. But you may try to open your site in new window from iframe `window.open(this.location.href);`
It will open your site in new window, but chances are popup may be blocked by browser by default.

**If your intension is to block other/unwanted websites** from embedding your site. You can use header `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`

```
<?php header("X-Frame-Options: DENY"); ?>
```

DENY – prevents the page from being rendered if it is contained in a frame

SAMEORIGIN – same as above, unless the page belongs to the same domain as the top-level frameset holder.

Answer (score 3):

This might work, but honestly, in general you shouldn't even be trying to do this.

```
  <iframe sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="http://mywebsite"></iframe>
```

The error you're getting says, "The user hasn't clicked on your iframe, and the iframe isn't part of the same domain as the top-level website, so therefore we don't trust your iframe enough to allow him to cause navigation."

This is a security feature of browsers to prevent evil people from hijacking users away from somebody else's website against their will.

It's also a UX feature. People probably don't want to leave their current website and go visit your iframe unless they've clicked on it.